# Translating to lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, select, lambda, anonymous-types

How would you translate specifically the select part of this linq expression into lambda?

```
var query2 = from method in typeof(double).GetMethods() // integrated method c# reflection
             orderby method.Name
             group method by method.Name into groups
             select new { MethodName = groups.Key, NumberOfOverloads = groups.Count()};
```

So far i have this:

```
 var methods = typeof(double).GetMethods();
 var query3 = methods.OrderBy(x => x.Name).GroupBy(y => y.Name);
```

I tried this for the select but i get compilor errors.

```
 var query3 = methods.OrderBy(x => x.Name).GroupBy(y => y.Name)
 .Select<new { MethodName = groups.Key, NumberOfOverloads = groups.Count()}>();
```

Would appreciate the help thanks.

Comment: The exact rules for translating query comprehensions into fluent syntax can be found in the C# specification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the exact translation. I have no idea why you need the `OrderBy` tho, considering you are not using the elements in the `Select`

```
var methods = typeof(double).GetMethods()
     .OrderBy(x=>x.Name)
     .GroupBy(x=>x.Name)
     .Select(x=> new { MethodName = x.Key, NumberOfOverloads = x.Count()});
```

The same result is obtained by

```
var methods = typeof(double).GetMethods()
 .GroupBy(x=>x.Name)
 .Select(x=> new { MethodName = x.Key, NumberOfOverloads = x.Count()});
```

and you save some computational time since you don't have to order the collection.

Comment: thanks, ive been trying to understand the linq operators. Do you know of any online resources that explain them well?

Comment: What made a difference for me is Jon Skeet's book C# in Depth, but you'll have to buy it. You can fid some material on his [blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/) but I don't think it's so easy to undertand for LINQ "beginners"